# Is there a difference in pronunciation between "wood" and "would"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

My friends and I were debating whether *would* and *wood* are pronounced differently.  Are they?

Comment: Is English your first language?

Comment: At least as I say them there's definitely a minor difference in inflection. Whether that qualifies as a different pronunciation, though, is something I'm not qualified to determine.

Comment: It depends on the register and your dialect.

Comment: @Third, yes (American) English is my first language.  Out of curiosity, why do you ask?

Comment: How much wood would a woodchuck chuck, if a woodchuck could chuck wood? Any time I've heard this tongue twister, *wood,* *would,* and *wood* all sound the same.

Comment: I'm intrigued to see at least one poster claiming there *is* potential for different pronunciations. We really should try this one with **prince** and **prints**.

Comment: @Fumblefingers: From the discussion of the pronunciation of **mall,** it sounded like some people in the U.K. don't rhyme **ball** and **maul.** Since the British dictionaries I've looked in give the pronunciations as /bɔːl/ and /mɔːl/, it'd be interesting to figure out what's going on here (unless people from the U.K. already know).

Comment: @Peter Shor: No dictionary lists every dialectal or other variation in pronunciation. And people *do* often imagine they enunciate and/or hear differences when they don't. I just like the *prince/prints* one because IMHO it's physically impossible to differentiate them, but a surprising number of people take some convincing of that fact.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: there's a quite distinct /t/ stop when I say "prints" that isn't there when I say "prince".  As a singer I'm used to listening to what I produce very carefully, and I can assure you you're wrong.

Comment: @Rhodri: I have only one ear, and not that many more phonemes either, to be honest. Plus this is a text-based forum. That's at least three reasons why I can't argue with you. But you might check with a few friends to see if *they* can tell which word you're saying (without you adding unnatural exaggeration, obviously).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree: I think unnatural exaggeration is one of the key aspects of pronunciation that makes most friend-tests fail... only using third-party material without context would be truly reliable!

Comment: @Cerberus: That would probably be very expensive to arrange, but of course it's the only valid way to establish the truth. I'd be interested to know what research *has* been done in this area, but I doubt the people with the cheque-books share that interest.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well, if you have a friend who is willing to help you, you could find and cut the recordings yourself, and use him as a guinea-pig. That would not be a scientific test, but it would be close enough to be quite convincing. The recordings would need to be standard English, and his score'd need to be quite high...

Comment: @Cerberus: Well I already gave three reasons why I personally wouldn't be much good at that. Although I *do* have a friend who's a statistician. He'd know exactly *how* high a score needs to be, to establish that it was true differentiation and not just chance. On a binary choice, even I know that 7 out of 10 might be chance, but 7,000,000 out of 10,000,000 definitely isn't. I just don't know the bits in between.

Answer (score 12):

It is generally very difficult for speakers to analyse their own pronunciation of a word, native speakers or no: our image of what the letters of a word look like affects our idea of how we think we pronounce it. Introspective analysis of pronunciation is notoriously unreliable.

That said, *wood* and *would* are pronounced **the same** in standard English. That is, there is no **meaningful** distinction in how both words sound if fully pronounced; if I were to cut out several instances of *would* and *wood* from recordings in standard English, without context, there is no way anyone could identify them as *woulds* and *woods* respectively.

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, they are both pronounced **/wʊd/**.
You can listen to both words on Howjsay.com:

- [wood](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=wood)
- [would](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=would)

**Edit:** if you say *would* fast or in an unaccented position, as in *that's not what she would do*, where either *not* and *do* or *she* has a strong accent, it is often pronounced **/wəd/**. It is also often pronounced **/d/** unaccented, or **/t/** before a voiceless stop, or not at all if preceded by a word ending on *-d*. It is often spelled *'d* when it is unaccented. But those are all variations on the standard pronunciation, as most words have them.

Comment: I tried quizzing my friend who volunteered to randomly say either "would, wood" or "wood, would" and was able to distinguish between them each time.  I invite others to try the same thing.  It's subtle, but I believe the tongue is more active for "would" -- it curls and remains lower in the mouth.

Comment: @KirkWoll: I don't think that counts! It should be a blind test: your friend knew what he was doing. I've had my friends do similar tests on other words, and they often pronounced the words much differently from the way they normally would. You should have your friend play back *woulds* and *woods* from natural recordings (and be careful to exclude the variations I mentioned).

Comment: I understand well the idea that we hear something in our heads that's not necessarily actually coming out verbally so I recorded myself saying both in a pattern I wrote out ("would wood would wood would would would wood wood wood would would wood wood"). Even before playing them back for a friend to see if she could pick them out I could clearly see the difference in the waveforms: "would" takes about 12% longer for me to say every time. So, pronounced the same, perhaps, but a clearly noticeable difference in the way I say them.

Comment: @MatthewFrederick: It is possible that they are pronounced slightly differently; but I just don't believe you could prove that in a non-blind test. By that I mean using data from speakers unaware of the test. If not, it would be like performing the Stanford Prison Experiment after having shown the participants a video of how the original went wrong, then telling them to behave absolutely naturally. One's pronunciation is involuntarily influenced by conscious and subconscious knowledge. I really think analysing existing recordings of natural speech is the only scientifically sound way to go.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and I do understand the possible and even likely bias in a non-blind test. That doesn't mean, however, that there *is* bias, nor does it mean that one's personal experience is automatically colored. There are plenty of likely homonyms that I can hear myself pronounce identically that allow me to be sufficiently certain that this is a case where it isn't so. It's fine that you'd prefer a scientific test; I suspect the OP doesn't require that level of accuracy.

Comment: @MatthewFrederick (if you're still around) Record a person saying the following : "would you like" and "wood you like"; in a different order five times; likewise with "I would like some wood"  and "I wood like some would" and ask a third person (without saying how many "errors" there are) to identify the ungrammatical sentence. I'm sure there must be phonological studies on wood vs would somewhere.

Comment: That would be an improvement, but even this set-up would be imperfect unless you record random conversations that were taking place anyway. A person reading a word from paper knowing that it is recorded may try to over-enunciate certain (perceived) letters/phonemes.

Answer (score 2):

In standard English would (the strong form, not the weak form) and wood have the
same pronunciation (OALD). This does not lead to confusion as the structures in which these two words are used are totally different.

Answer (score 1):

In the Australian English which I know, *wood* and *would* are pronounced itdentically. The only difference that occurs to me has already been mentioned by others that *would* has an additional unstressed pronunciation that *wood* lacks.

Answer (score 0):

> My friends and I were debating whether would and wood are pronounced differently. Are they?

You have given no context and have not indicated an interest in various possible accents or stresses. I assume you want an answer in general terms:

The following sentences are pronounced **identically** in Standard British English.

"In this sentence the word 'wood' is wrong."

"In this sentence the word 'would' is wrong."

**Would** and **wood** are pronounced the same.

Answer (score -2):

I believe there are two different pronunciations for two different meanings of the word "would".

If you are referring the most common meaning then the answer is no, both of "wood" and "would" sounds as "wud".

Comment: What are the 'two different meanings of the word "would"` to which you are referring?

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/would

Comment: your link defined one variation of the word with one defined prounciation.  Thus I ask again, which are the two that you believe to have discrete pronunciations?

Comment: @Kirk Woll: I think what Jamie is getting at is that "would" is often ennunciated with a *schwa* (neutral vowel), which doesn't happen with "wood". So it's not so much a difference in meaning as a difference in emphasis. You could argue forever about whether emphasis is just a subdivision of meaning anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Excellent remark. I have added this to my answer, if you don't mind.

Answer (score -4):

I think historically the *l* in *would* was a hint that you would add a little bit of tongue on pronunciation. While you could pronounce *wood* directly.

Same as *while* and *why* and *wide* and *wild*.

Edited : Oh! great. Instead of try to find reference yourself you guy just downvote me without your own reference or even argument

OK You know what? In wiktionary there was a reference state that `would` was derived from old english word `wolde` which pronounce /ˈwol.de/

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/would#Etymology

And you guy think english people just skip `l` immediately after it changed into `would` ?

Comment: Needs reference.

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry I don't, it just speculation from most study about languages I have so far. Like the old english would pronounce Sword as /swurd/ not /sɔːd/. It almost always safe to assume that the sound mutation is often happen and the written form is writing the original pronunciation

Comment: My thoughts exactly. It's exactly the same as the silent H in while or where (still pronounced in some areas of the world, but not others). Eventually while may lose the pronunciation of the H much like the L in would.